# OpenStreetMap not displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

What am I doing wrong? Maps are not displayed. I add libs: osmdroid-android-5.1 and slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1. I made .zip with offline maps.

Activity.java:

```
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import java.lang.String;

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    private int MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    private double MAP_DEFAULT_LATITUDE = 49.292192;
    private double MAP_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE = 19.959055;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM);
        mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(MAP_DEFAULT_LATITUDE, MAP_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE));
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.tatry">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <supports-screens
            android:anyDensity="true"
            android:resizeable="false"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.tatry.MapsActivity">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true">
    </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I haven't found anything at my online researches.

I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: I suggest the use of MapBox. It uses OSM data, works fine on web site using Leaflet and the Android SDK is good. I wanted to use OSM data and after searching, I found MapBox a pretty nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue for osmdroid not rendering correctly the preview mode of android studio. It's only an android studio thing and it should be fixed in 5.6.

Also, 5.1 is pretty old at this point, you may want to consider using a new version.